# Cant See or Edit Components in Android Studio Layout

Tags: android

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NzLE.jpg)

I tried to create a Hello World using Kotlin but for whatever reason the components are not showing up normally, such as you can visually see their attributes and edit them within the layout.

PS I can provide any other info needed

Comment: there is and error with your editText2 and your root layout is ConstraintLayout. maybe its because of it. just change the ConstaintLayout to a LinearLayout or sth and try again. if it didnt helpt show the xml text here...

Comment: Top right corner of the editor, you have a red icon. The errors are there